# rails add foreign key on imported file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, csv, model, import

I’m trying to set the foreign key on an imported list. My idea was to create a before_save callback to update the foreign key using a session variable. However, my understanding is that you can’t readily or shouldn’t access session variables from the model. If that’s the case, what other options to I have. My code is as follows:

In the model:

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, :email, :mobile, :restaurant _id
   belongs_to :restaurant

    before_save :add_restaurant

    def add_restaurant
     contact = Contact.find_by_restaurant_id(session[:current_restaurant])
     contact.restaurant_id = (session[:current_restaurant])
    end

  def self.import(file)
    CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
    contact = find_by_first_name_and_last_name(row["first_name"], row["last_name"]) || new
    contact.attributes = row.to_hash.slice(*accessible_attributes)
    contact.save!
    end
  end
end
```

In the controller:

```
def import
    Contact.import(params[:file])
    redirect_to contacts_path, notice: "List imported"
end
```

Comment: Is there really a space between restaurant and _id above?

Comment: I still haven't found a solution to this problem and I don't know where to go from the code above. Some help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This question was answered more thoroughly 6 months later, [here.][1]

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17719660/rails-4-csv-import-and-setting-a-value-to-a-key-value

Answer (score 0):

You could find the restaurant first and add the contact to the restaurant contacts.

```
def self.import(file)
  CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
    contact = find_by_first_name_and_last_name(row["first_name"], row["last_name"]) || new
    contact.attributes = row.to_hash.slice(*accessible_attributes)
    restaurant = Restaurant.find_by_id(r_id)    # Get the restaurant here
    restaurant.contacts << contact              # This will do a save immediately
  end
end
```

Comment: this didn't work for me but i have a silly question. The restaurant_id is stored in a session variable when the user logs in. When they upload the file, the columns in the CSV are first_name, last_name, email, and mobile with no reference to the restaurant_id (since the user won't know it and i don't want to have to make them know it). How does restaurant = Restaurant.find_by_id(r_id) find the restaurant_id associated with the current user without accessing the session variable.

Comment: Ah - I see.  The session is available in the controller, you'd need to pass that to the import_file method.  Because of this, I'd switch it up and get the restaurant in the controller, then call restaurant.import_contacts(file) and put it in the restaurant model.