# Rails CSV import with param for each record set from session value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

The following sequence of creating records from a CSV file, as defined in the model

```
def self.import(file)
    CSV.foreach(file.path, :col_sep => "\t", headers: true, skip_blanks: true) do |row|
begin

  @analysis_id => session[:analysis_id]

  Registration.create(
    :balance => row[10]
  )
```

fails as session data is not recognized.  Adding params to the form:

```
<%= form_tag import_registrations_path, multipart: true do %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag "registration[analysis_id]", session[:analysis_id] %>
```

passes the parameters

```
"registration"=>{"analysis_id"=>"1"}, "file"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00000103bbe4d8
```

with the creation stated as

```
  Registration.create(
    :analysis_id => analysis_id,
    :balance => row[10]
  )
```

or alternatively `:analysis_id => params[;registration][;analysis_id],`
but the creation action fails due to undefined local variable or method `analysis_id'

I'm clearly missing what gets handed over the the import action and how to insert it into the import flow.

Answer (score 0):

Controller needs to specify:

```
  Registration.import(params[:file], params[:analysis_id])
```

and model invokes the param

```
  def self.import(file, analysis_id)
```

and the following will execute

```
  Registration.create(
    :analysis_id => analysis_id,
    :balance => row[10]
  )
```

Answered [here already, but Google roulette did not pan out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17719660/rails-4-csv-import-and-setting-a-value-to-a-key-value)